# Sending mails to multiple users using python

Tags: python, email, smtplib, spam-prevention

I recently found a code to send emails using python. It was only for a single user so I modified it to take emails from a txt file which stores the email on every line and then send them mails. However what I found is that the mails end up in the spam folder(in case of Gmail) or the Junk folder (in case of hotmail or live). Is it possible to change the code so that the message lands in the inbox instead of being filtered as spam? Did I get something wrong?

```
import smtplib,sys

server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 587

sender = 'my-username@gmail.com'
subject = 'Gmail SMTP Test'
body = 'blah blah blah'

"Sends an e-mail to the specified recipient."



session = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)

session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo
session.login(sender, 'my-password!')

f = open('emails.txt')
for line in f:
  recipient = line
  print recipient
  headers = ["From: " + sender,
       "Subject: " + subject,
       "To: " + recipient]
  headers = "\r\n".join(headers)
  session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)

f.close()
session.quit()
```

Comment: How many recipients are in the file?

Comment: If they are ending up in spam, check that your emails are not about viagra, hot singles in my area, or nigerian business propositions ..

Comment: @wim Ofcourse its not about that. Its a simple one liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very difficult question, because the spam classification is not done by you. (Obviously! If anyone could make their messages "not spam" then of course the spammers would do that too.)

There are various things you should do if you are seriously thinking about sending large-scale email, involving authenticating servers etc. Unless you are an expert, you should engage the services of a mailing company to do them.

Comment: The reason why I am confused is because, if I send the same mail with the same subject to the same email-id using my gmail account, the message lands in the inbox. However when I use the python script above, it lands in spam. How can you exaplain that?

Comment: Gmail probably sets a whole bunch more SMTP headers when you send via their web service. Some you may be able to send programmatically; some may be taking account of the fact that messages sent by hand are much less likely to be counted as spam.

Comment: By the way, if the recipient explicitly marks your messages as non-spam once, this should cease to be a problem.

Comment: So is there a moderate workaround for this? Ofcourse once the recipient marks my mails as not-spam it wont be a problem, but the thing is, most of the times people dont check spam. Why I am using this script is because with gmail its not possible to send multiple emails at a single without revealing the email addresses of all the recipients to everyone in the list.

Comment: Sure it is: just put them in the BCC field.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using PHP to send emails and I was able to get my emails out of the spam folder just by changing the subject and body - making them slightly more meaningful and less test-like.

Try out different things - a subject like "Invoice from Jack's Store" or "Introducing you to Twitter." Or just take the subject and the body from an actual email and put it in your test.

Comment: The reason why I am confused is because, if I send the same mail with the same subject to the same email-id using my gmail account, the message lands in the inbox. However when I use the python script above, it lands in spam.

Answer (score 0):

Yes One Way is there but there is time wasting method.....

This is your Code:

put the sleep method and replace with this code

```
    import smtplib,sys
    import time
    server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port = 587

    sender = 'my-username@gmail.com'
    subject = 'Gmail SMTP Test'
    body = 'blah blah blah'

    "Sends an e-mail to the specified recipient."



    session = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)

    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo
    session.login(sender, 'my-password!')

    f = open('emails.txt')
    for line in f:
      recipient = line
      print recipient
      headers = ["From: " + sender,
           "Subject: " + subject,
           "To: " + recipient]
      headers = "\r\n".join(headers)
      session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
      time.sleep(3)
    f.close()
    session.quit()
```

IF any other problem comment....:)